# Creating a floating activity like in contacts app

Tags: android, android-activity

I've been looking for how to implement an activity which won't be in full screen but not a dialog style. It is desired to be as follows:

[image]

I've tried some methods like AppTheme Dialog but I'm not getting the result I'm expecting. Any ideas how can I achieve that?

Comment: You can use `BottomSheetDialog` to achieve that

Comment: Ok. I'll dig a little bit on it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use `BottomSheetBehaviour`

It is pretty easy to use and has a nice animation. Take a look at a simple guide [here](http://www.androidtutorialshub.com/android-material-design-bottom-sheets-tutorial/). Sorry, I can't post the whole process here in detail. But for a quick implementation.

1. Create a class

```
public class CustomBottomSheetDialogFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, container, false);
        return v;
    } 
}
```

2. Fill in your bottom by calling the class

```
new CustomBottomSheetDialogFragment().show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Dialog");
```